# How to solve mirror class error in flutter?

Tags: flutter, dart, dart-mirrors

I have been searching for a solution for this error for two days now

```
'type 'MethodMirrorImpl' is not a subtype of type 'VariableMirror'
```

in my flutter application but I can't get any solution.

here is my code:

My function:

```
final DataQueryBuilder queryBuilder = DataQueryBuilder();
  Future<List<dynamic>> getData() async {
    queryBuilder.pageSize = 50;

    try {
      final list = await Backendless.data.withClass<Movie>().find(queryBuilder);
      return list;
    }
    catch (e) {
      print(e);
    }
    return [];
  }
```

My Model class:

```
@reflector
class Movie{

  String _name;
  String _type;
  String _channel;
  String _day;
  String _hour;
  String _minutes;
  String _ampm;
  String _url;
  String _plot;

  String get name => _name;

  String get type => _type;

  String get plot => _plot;

  String get url => _url;

  String get ampm => _ampm;

  String get minutes => _minutes;

  String get hour => _hour;

  String get day => _day;

  String get channel => _channel;

}
```

My main configuration:

```
import 'package:flutter/material.dart';
import 'package:newtest/provider/MoviesProvider.dart';
import 'package:newtest/widgets/containers.dart';
import 'package:backendless_sdk/backendless_sdk.dart';
import 'package:provider/provider.dart';
import 'main.reflectable.dart';

void main() {
  initializeReflectable();
  runApp(MyApp());
}

class MyApp extends StatelessWidget {


  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return MaterialApp(
      debugShowCheckedModeBanner: false,
      title: 'Flutter Demo',
      theme: ThemeData(
        primarySwatch: Colors.blue,
      ),
      home: ChangeNotifierProvider<MoviesProvider>(
        create: (_)=> MoviesProvider(),
        child: MyHomePage(title: 'Flutter Demo Home Page'),
      )
    );
  }

}


class MyHomePage extends StatefulWidget {
  MyHomePage({Key key, this.title}) : super(key: key);
  final String title;

  @override
  _MyHomePageState createState() => _MyHomePageState();
}


class _MyHomePageState extends State<MyHomePage> {

  @override
  void initState() {
    super.initState();
    Backendless.initApp("appId", "androidId", "iosId");
  }
```

....................................................
...................................................
..........

Comment: what version of backendless_sdk are you using?

Comment: @Juanes30 backendless_sdk: ^6.1.0

Comment: why don't you try simplifying the model, remove the underscore and eliminate the gets. Example `String _name` to `String name`;

Comment: @Juanes30 already done this and gave me the same error.

Comment: Have you already tested using version 1.0.0?

Comment: could you please show the configuration you made in your main file?

Comment: @Juanes30 yes at first I tried with backendless version 1.0.0 but it gave me the same error

Comment: @Juanes30 I edited my question and added my main configuration

Comment: you added the `build_runner` dependency in `dev_dependencies` in your `pubspec.yaml` file

Comment: @Juanes30 yes
dev_dependencies:
  flutter_test:
    sdk: flutter
  build_runner: ^1.0.0

Comment: and you have executed the following command before running your application. `flutter packages pub run build_runner build`

Comment: @Juanes30 yes and it gave me this trace 

[INFO] 5.3s elapsed, 0/2 actions completed.
[INFO] 6.3s elapsed, 0/2 actions completed.
[INFO] 14.2s elapsed, 0/2 actions completed.
[WARNING] No actions completed for 15.1s, waiting on:
  - reflectable:reflectable on lib/main.dart
  - reflectable:reflectable on test/widget_test.dart

[INFO] 16.2s elapsed, 0/2 actions completed.
[INFO] 17.4s elapsed, 0/2 actions completed.

Comment: `'type 'MethodMirrorImpl' is not a subtype of type 'VariableMirror'` the above error occurs when you run `flutter packages pub run build_runner build`?

Comment: @Juanes30 No it happens when hot restart or run the app, and  I thought if removed build_runner: ^1.0.0 from pubspec.yaml it will solve the problem but it gives me the same error

Comment: would be to validate in this guide to see the missing configurations. [link](https://backendless.com/how-to-use-custom-classes-in-flutter-sdk)

Comment: @Juanes30 they send me that link and I did exactly what is written in the example

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/227981/discussion-between-juanes30-and-peter-estifanos).